# angular2 download object using pre-signed url from s3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, httprequest

I'm using the AWS SDK to generate pre-signed download url from S3 and and I have already done that part. I can copy the generated pre-signed url into browser and the chrome will automatically download the file.

I want to achieve the same thing in Angular2,  basically simulate clicking that link. So I wrote the following code:

app.component.ts

```
public downloadFile() { 
  this.downloadService.downloadFile(this.downloadLink)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });}
```

download.service.ts

```
    public downloadFile(downloadLink: string) {
      return this.http.get(downloadLink)
        .map((response) => {
            return response;
      });
    }
```

It indeed printed out the file content in the console but it didn't trigger the downloading. Has anybody got an idea what's the correct way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the type of the file you are trying to download

Comment: What settings are you using at S3 bucket side ? When I try to download file using same approach , it is giving me content security policy error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to download a CSV file change the mime type for your own file.

```js
public downloadFile(downloadLink: string) {
          return this.http.get(downloadLink)
            .map((response) => {
               const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv'})
               window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
          });
       }
```

Comment: is there any alternative to download and save file as `.txt`  ?